# silent switch and radio streaming (background also)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I create simple app to stream audio. And it's work perfectly with Volume Buttons. Play in background mode. But when i switch the "Silent switch" music still plays. Why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://87.98.235.103:9768/"]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setPlayBtn:nil];
    [self setStopBtn:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
- (IBAction)pressedPlay:(id)sender {

    [self.player play];

}

- (IBAction)pressedStop:(id)sender {

    [self.player pause];
}
```

In **application didFinishLaunching**:

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];

UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

And in plist i have:

```
Required background modes: App plays audio
```